# pexpect interact() duplicated bash output

Tags: python, pexpect

Hello everyone! Currently I'm trying to create an interactive python environment to call bash scripts - using pexpect. For explanatory purpose, let's look at following code and my corresponding output. It should just spawn an instance of bash and echo foobar.

```python
import pexpect
p = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash -i -c 'echo foobar'")
p.interact()
```

This gives me the output

```python
foobar
foobar
```

This is (at least for me) not the expected output, since it seems to duplicate the output line. This problem goes even further: some script calls flood the terminal with empty lines, which is very unfortunate, since I want to have outputs from the last call on the screen. I guess the cause of this problem has something to do with the example I gave above. You might think I don't need to use p.interact(). For the example that's certainly correct, but my real script needs to be versatile and user interaction is to be expected.
I hope someone can help me with that - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Seems like the pexpect module was outdated.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pexpect
```

solved the probem.